# Arrow Keys not Working inside the contentEditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The arrow keys does not work.

HTML:

```
<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'model_number','357')" onClick="showEdit(this);"></td>
```

JQUERY:

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj, column, id) {
    $(editableObj).css("background", "#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
    $.ajax({
        url: "edit_product.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: 'column=' + column + '&editval=' + editableObj.innerHTML + '&id=' + id,
        success: function(data) {
            $(editableObj).css("background", "#FDFDFD");
        }
    });
}

function showEdit(editableObj) {
    $(editableObj).css("background", "#FFF");
}
```

Help me with this. THanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Please cheack that weather you have included any jquery scroll plugin . If you have included any plugin please remove it and try it.

Comment: Wow.. Thanks Mr. Kathiravan . I have checked and removed the same. now it works like a charm